# Simple prolog, beginner learning

Tags: prolog

I have the following prolog;

```
customer(Invoice,_,Surname,_,Town),(Town='LA';Town='NEWYORK'),
order(Invoice,Code,_),
item(Code,_,_,_,_,_,_)
```

The above prolog produces the results;

```
Invoice = 51, Surname = 'Hally', Town = 'LA', Code = 54 ;

Invoice = 51, Surname = 'Hally', Town = 'LA', Code = 58 ;

Invoice = 51, Surname = 'Hally', Town = 'LA', Code = 85 ;

Invoice = 51, Surname = 'Hally', Town = 'LA', Code = 148 ;

Invoice = 71, Surname = 'Steptoe', Town = 'NEWYORK', Code = 148 ;

Invoice = 71, Surname = 'Steptoe', Town = 'NEWYORK', Code = 176 ;

Invoice = 73, Surname = 'Ahmed', Town = 'NEWYORK', Code = 180 ;
```

As can be seen above there are two results with the same code (148), how can I only return these two results? I have tried adding `,(Code=Code).` but it does not work.

I really am new to this!

Additionally I am attempting to store the prolog into a new predicate to return the two surnames only such as below,

```
getDuplicateOrders(Surname1, Surname2):- (prolog).
```

But I get an error saying static variables shouldn't be used!

Comment: How general a solution are you after? Are you looking for possibly more than two different towns, and *all* with the same code, or *two or more* with the same code?

Comment: Only two towns will ever be used, and I would like to filter the result to same code different towns. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to separate out the codes and then compare them:

```
customer(Invoice1, _, Surname1, _, 'LA'),
customer(Invoice2, _, Surname2, _, 'NEWYORK'),
order(Invoice1, Code, _),
order(Invoice2, Code, _),    % We want the same code
item(Code,_,_,_,_,_,_).
```

This code, of course, assumes that *Invoice* is unique for each locality (*e.g.*, `LA` or `NEWYORK`). If this is not the case, then there needs to be another way in the data to distinguish codes for the different orders, if they are, indeed, different. If one needs to simply ensure uniqueness of the invoices, `dif/2` would work here:

```
customer(Invoice1, _, Surname1, _, 'LA'),
customer(Invoice2, _, Surname2, _, 'NEWYORK'),
dif(Invoice1, Invoice2),
order(Invoice1, Code, _),
order(Invoice2, Code, _),    % We want the same code
item(Code,_,_,_,_,_,_).
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am from an imperative programming background, logical programming really opens up the brain. It really does go about things in a different way/concept.

Comment: @false for which variables? I'm assuming `Invoice1` and `Invoice2` will already be unique for different towns/localities. And `Surname1` and `Surname2` might match, but that would be OK since they're different towns/localities.

Comment: @lurker: Yes, you assume this. But if you read the answer out of context (that's what answers are read here most of the time), it somewhat suggests that `Invoice1` and `Invoice2` are different by their different name.

Comment: @false, actually, thinking on that further, if invoices aren't unique to the locality, then the OP needs another "key" which would differentiate the records for those two localities. Inserting a `dif(Invoice1, Invoice2)` seems could possibly be an incorrect solution because if there are two same invoices but one from `LA` and one from `NEWYORK`, then there needs to be a different way to get their order codes, assuming their different orders. I think there's not enough information about the problem to support simply adding a `dif/2` and consider it correct.

Comment: @lurker: I see primarily the false suggestion that is implied by your current answer, which is a very frequent false misconception of beginners.

Comment: @false I guess it's the devil I know versus the devil I don't know. ;) I did update the answer, with a caveated suggestion for `dif/2`. It's, indeed, an important point.

Comment: The first answer was correct for my use case, but thanks for further explaining the problem in more detail for other use cases.